# Precession of a flywheel on earth

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, coriolis-effect, precession

I’m currently working on a mechanical problem and I’ve got a couple of questions. First, let me describe the problem. We’ve got a flywheel somewhere on the surface of the earth spinning merrily. It is mounted on the earth but not mounted at the equator. I would like to describe the forces acting on the flywheel.

To begin with, we focused on the coriolis force. Using earth as the rotating reference systems and considering points on the spinning flywheel we’ve derived an expression for the Coriolis force on the flywheel. So far all good.

However, since we’ve the axis of rotation of the flywheel rotating about earth's axis of rotation, we’ve got precession. Solving [Euler's equations for rigid body dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_equations_(rigid_body_dynamics)?fbclid=IwAR36t1fNNQ9gqLUal2gN4p3WPV7oJtccTBXzUiRkZoYfxGZuqVuJAFJNPH8) does, indeed, produce the results that there are two torques exerted on the flywheel that are essentially in the form of a constant multiplied with a $\sin$ and $\cos$ term respectively. A classical precession, if I understood it correctly.

The Euler equations are solved by putting a body fixed reference system in the flywheel and then describing the total angular velocity in that coordinate system. Since the moments of inertia are known, the equations aren’t that difficult to solve.

To describe all the forces acting on the flywheel, how would I proceed? Are the gyroscopic precession forces accounted for by the Coriolis force? If not, why?
If they are not accounted for I assume I’ll have to transform either the precession torques or the Coriolis effect into the other coordinate system. What coordinate system (since we’ve considered both a earth fixed and flywheel fixed system) would be best to consider?

Thanks in advance. If there are uncertainties or areas that need clarification, please ask. Sorry for the lack of actual formulae and images. I think I might be able to add a few scans of my work in case of interest.